# Make (column id, value) tuples from pandas dataframe values in a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to convert every value in a `pandas` dataframe to a tuple of the form: `(col_id, val)` where `col_id` is the integer order of the column and `val` is the very value at that location, and output that in the form a list of lists which ignores the tuples whose `val==0`.

Example:

```
                   0   1   2   3
document0001      48   0   3   0
document0002       0   4   0   0
```

Output:

```
                    
[[(0,48), (2,3)],
 [(1,4)]]
```

I think I can iterate or write a custom function with `apply` to make the tuples but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Your example shows that there every column has at least a zero. Is this correct for your whole data or could the expected output also be [[(0,48), (2,3,1)],
 [(1,4)]] ?

Comment: This is not guaranteed, I can guarantee there are at least one non-zero value in each row. In any case there shouldn't be a `(2,3,1)` triple, all must tuples over rows, and your example would translate to an additional `(2, 1)` in the second row of the output beside `(1,4)` -- order is irrelevant. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

This does it

1. transpose and calc a new column which picks out none zero value
2. iterate other the columns of transposed dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                   0   1   2   3
document0001      48   0   3   0
document0002       0   4   0   0"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

dft = df.T
l = []
for c in dft.columns:
    l.append(list(dft.loc[dft[c]!=0,c].to_frame().itertuples(name=None)))
    
l
```

**output**

```
[[('0', 48), ('2', 3)], [('1', 4)]]
```

Comment: Thank you but this outputs a `list`, so the document boundaries are lost. It's supposed to return a `list` of `list`, where each inner list corresponds to a document.

Comment: Ok - as much as I dislike iterating in pandas,  love solution will do what you want

Comment: I appreciate it, but I wrote that I am looking for something other than low-level iterating in pandas, I share your detestation of this style as well; but thanks! your answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

Read the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[48, 0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0, 0]], index=['document0001', 'document0002'], columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])
```

Turn rows into columns (transpose):

```
ndf = df.T
```

Merge columns to one value, assuming that there is always one value a zero. This method does *not* work if there are no zeroes:

```
sdf =pd.DataFrame(ndf['document0001']+ndf['document0002']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Turn the values in a list of tuples:

```
sdf[(sdf.T != 0).any()].to_records()
```

Expected output:

rec.array([(0, 48), (1,  4), (2,  3)],
dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('0', '<i8')])

Comment: Many thanks, it is important though to keep the boundaries of `document` rows in a `list` of `list`, but the output from the code you provide is a flat `list`..